# Tensorflow Classification with Alpha Numeric Codes as Features

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm attempting to build Tensorflow classification model that uses alpha numeric codes as features. Here are a few examples from the dataset:

```
Code1   Code2   Code3   Class1  Class2
K21     LZ82    RR90    0       1
K99     LZ82    OPN1    0       1
N21     Z93     Z33     1       0
```

I understand that I need to convert these alpha numeric strings to vectors/integers/floats of some kind. I have already tried Bag of Words (BOW) across the corpus, with min-max scaling, but I did not achieve very good accuracy from my model.

In my overall corpus of 6000 codes, some of the codes are used up to 40,000 times, so there was quite a range of values from BOW. So for example, after min-max scaling I had data that looked like this:

```
Code1           Code2           Code3           Class1  Class2
0.8736080064    0.2166280429    0.0008203277    0       1
```

As additional information, here is my network architecture:

```
const model = tf.sequential()
model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 200, activation: 'relu', inputShape [this.NUM_CODES_PER_RECORD] }))
model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 150, activation: 'relu' }))
model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 100, activation: 'relu' }))
model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: this.NUM_CLASSES, activation: 'softmax' }))
```

From my understanding, it seems that Word Embeddings are more related to Natural Language Processing than my task, so I have not attempted Embeddings yet.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to transform these alphanumeric codes into vectors/integers/floats for my model.

Comment: Have you tried "one hot encoding"? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I thought about one hot encoding, but with 6000 unique codes I thought it would be too sparse.

Comment: Yeah, but that should be ok.

Comment: Would you suggest that each code be transformed into a one hot array with length 6000? So in my example I would have 3 arrays of length 6000?

Comment: That's correct.